# Single tag causes chrome to break?

Tags: google-chrome, rendering

Okay so I have run into this weird bug that I have no clue how to proceed with.

I am building a fairly basic static website, just HTML/CSS and a bit of Jquery for slight animations nothing big.

The html is for the page is

```
 <!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Quick Metal Finishers</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header id="topHeader">
    <div id="topName">
        <h1>Quick Metal Finishers</h1>
        <h2>Electroplating | Powder Coating | Metal Painting</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="topContact">
        <h2>Questions?</h2>
        <h1>EMAIL NOW: <strong>info@quickmetalfinishers.com</strong></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
</header>
<hr/>
<nav id="topNav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div role="main">

<!--Awesome image slidy thingy-->
<div id='coin-slider'>
    <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src='images/main_img1.jpg' >
        <span>
            Description for img01
        </span>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <img src='images/main_img2.jpg' >
        <span>
            Description for imgN
        </span>
    </a>
</div>

<!--Next up we have the business blurb-->
<div id="mainCatchy">
<div id="mainCatchyLine">
Choose Us for we are the best this should be slighly long.
</div>
<div id="mainCatchyDescription">
<p>
Fusce varius euismod lorem, nec semper ante ullamcorper condimentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu tortor eget nunc blandit rutrum. Praesent hendrerit ante sed nulla molestie gravida vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia. Nam quis cursus massa. Dapibus, turpis quis ultricies tincidunt , elit augue facilisis turpis, et suscipit nibh eros eget tortor. Vivamus eleifend dictum.
</p>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
</div>


</div>
<footer>

</footer>
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#coin-slider').coinslider({ width: 960, navigation: false, delay: 5000 });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is

```
html{
    background:hsl(50, 7%, 84%) url(images/bg-body.png) repeat top left;
}

body{
    width:960px;
    margin:4em auto;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}

#topHeader{
    font-family:Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:4em 77px 0 77px ;
}

#topName{
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    vertical-align:baseline;
}

#topName h1, #topName h2{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:14pt;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#topName h2{
    font-size:10pt;
    color:#808080;
}

#topContact{
    width:auto;
    float:right;
    margin-top:3pt;
    text-align:right;
}
#topContact h1, #topContact h2{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:10pt;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#808080;
}
#topContact strong{
    color:#000;
}

/*Top Navigation*/
#topNav{
    font-family:Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:0 77px 0 77px ;
}
#topNav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 0 1em 0;
}
#topNav li{
    display:inline;
    margin-right:5ex;
}
#topNav a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:11pt;
    color:#808080;
}

#mainCatchy{
    margin:2em 77px 0 77px;
    padding:0;
}

#mainCatchyLine{
    width:240px;
    float:left;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:16pt;
    padding:20px 30px;
    color:#333;
}
#mainCatchyDescription{
    float:left;
    width: 506px;   
    font-size:10pt;
    color:#555;
}
/*Generic Styles*/
hr{
    border:none;
    border-top:1px dotted rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    height:0;
    width:98%;
    margin:2em auto 0.7em auto;
}
```

The issue is the page doesn't render in chrome at all. The blue rotaty thing in the title bar just keeps spinning with nothing rendering.

Here's the kicker: If I remove the `<p>` tag from just that div and place the text either by itself or inside another `<div>`, chrome has no issue rendering it.

The page as of now works flawlessly in firefox.

I have no idea what might be causing this issue.

EDIT:

I have uploaded the code to 
http://dm.finearts.yorku.ca/~raveesh/test/

Comment: Do you have a live example? Without those JS files and images, there's nothing wrong, it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the issue seems to be dev version of chrome that I was using, it works fine on the regular channel version. There seem to be a lot of rendering bugs in the Dev channel.

Cheers,
-tR